# Unknown layer: KerasLayer when i try to load_model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

When i try to save my model as hdf5

```
path = 'path.h5'
model.save(path)
```

then load the model again

```
my_reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer
```

Any help ? I'm using

```
tensorflow version:  2.2.0  
keras version:  2.3.0-tf
```

Comment: Hi. I can't reproduce this error with tf version '1.14.0' and keras '2.2.4-tf', maybe there's a problem with your installation. Have you tried reinstalling tf/keras, or loading a different model created by someone else?

Comment: yes, i tried to load a different model but didn't work

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I just found a solution that worked for me

```
my_reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
       (path),
       custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer}
)
```

Comment: @antonioACR1 hub is tensorflow_hub module. imported as "import tensorflow_hub as hub"

Comment: i also face this error when i try to load tf hub model after save to local env. this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may also face this problem if you have made a custom model and not included `get_config` method in the custom layers and models.

```py
class CustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sublayer, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sublayer = layer

    def call(self, x):
        return self.sublayer(x)

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        config = {
            "sublayer": keras.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.sublayer),
        }
        return {**base_config, **config}

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        sublayer_config = config.pop("sublayer")
        sublayer = keras.saving.deserialize_keras_object(sublayer_config)
        return cls(sublayer, **config)
```

[Check for more](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving#custom_objects)