# Unknown layer: KerasLayer. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have trained a model on google colab by adding a layer to resnet. Here is the model:

import tensorflow_hub as hub # Provides pretrained models

```
resnet_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/5"
# Download ResNet model and save as Keras layer
# Trainable : False means we don't want to train it further
resnet_layer = hub.KerasLayer(resnet_url,
                            trainable=False,
                            input_shape=(256,256,3))

# Create model
resnet_model=tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Puts images through downloaded model first
    resnet_layer,
    # Define we will use 20 classes
    Dense(2,
        activation="softmax")
])
```

It works fine on colab notebook. But when I export and want to deploy it into a flask service using the code below:

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import io
import os
from PIL import Image
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)



def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('resnet_model_1.h5')
    print(" * Model loaded!")

def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image

print(" * Loading Keras model...")
get_model()

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(256, 256))
    
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'dog': prediction[0][0],
            'cat': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

I get this nasty error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 988, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 579, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 850, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 333, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 389, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 234, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/pc3/dev/flaskservice/predict_app.py", line 39, in <module>
    get_model()
  File "/home/pc3/dev/flaskservice/predict_app.py", line 26, in get_model
    model = load_model('resnet_model_1.h5')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 562, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

my tensorflow version on colab is `2.8.2` and my local ubuntu machine on which I deply the model it is `2.9.1`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61831193/15363841) that this error has been resolved by passing `,custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer}` to load_model. But for me this results in all images are classifed as cat. So clearly it messes up somthing in the model.

So I'm left clueless and appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that these lines are added before calling your inference, as you need to call an argmax to specify which category is the dominant one in your prediction.

```
list_of_categories = ["dog", "cat"]
pred = list_of_categories[np.argmax(prediction)]
response = pred
```

Comment: The error occurs at mode loading line. So your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: My answer is relevant ONLY after you pass ,custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer} in the model loading. KerasLayer is an object of Keras which is not saved during model serialization (model.save of keras), and has to be passed explicitly later.
It should not "mess up" your model.

Comment: still get the error. Kindly answer with full code that you reckon to be the solution.