# Error while deployment of deep learning model using flask

Tags: flask, deep-learning, deployment, command, google-colaboratory

i am making a project on dog breed prediction using image and i want to deploy it on a website i was using flask i took help from chatgpt and multiple youtube tutorials bcoz its my first time using flask but when i run my app.py file i cmd it gives me this error

```
# Load the pre-trained TensorFlow model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model path")
# Function to preprocess the image

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Open the image using Pillow
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Resize image to match model's expected input shape
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    
    # Convert image to numpy array
    img_array = np.array(img)
    
    # Normalize pixel values to range [0, 1]
    img_array = img_array / 255.0
    
    # Expand dimensions to match model's input shape (add batch dimension)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    
    return img_array


# Route to handle image upload and prediction
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    
    file = request.files['file']
    
    # Check if the file is empty
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    
    # Check if the file is an image
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Read the image file
        img = Image.open(file)
        # Preprocess the image
        img_array = preprocess_image(img)
        # Perform prediction using the loaded TensorFlow model
        prediction = model.predict(img_array)
        # Process prediction result (you may need to adjust this based on your model)
        # For demonstration, let's assume the model outputs a class index
        predicted_class_index = np.argmax(prediction)
        # Convert class index to a human-readable prediction
        class_labels = ['Class 0', 'Class 1', 'Class 2']  # Replace with your class labels
        prediction_result = class_labels[predicted_class_index]
        return f'The predicted class is: {prediction_result}'
    
    return 'Invalid file format'

# Function to check if the file extension is allowed
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
```

i got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ykrW.png)

help me in this i am getting this error and i am not able to understand if the error is in flask code or my DL model code

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the given error is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61831193/15363841). You can solve the problem by passing custom_objects:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
       "model path",
       custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer}
)
```

You also need to check `preprocess_image()` input. It seems that you send a file to it (not the file path).

Comment: thank you the deployment was done successfully but i got other error is that my model after the deployment is predicting wrong